# $(...).sparkline is not a function (jQuery Sparklines)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, sparklines

I'm currently running into an issue when using a package called [jQuery Sparklines by Gareth Watts](https://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#s-about). **Does anyone have any experience with this package?** It seems to be pretty outdated but some people still use it here..

I am importing the package via script tag in a Flask view using regular ol' script tags:

`<script src="/custom/css/JS/jquery-sparklines.js"></script>`

And have checked the console to make sure jQuery is also installed and loaded **before** I load the script tag above.

I noticed the issue when I was trying to emulate the [example jFiddle in the docs](http://jsfiddle.net/gwatts/PfzXg/):

I was able to create a working version of the fiddle [myself here](http://jsfiddle.net/kev_can_c0de/3dyt7k6L/) but only by adding jQuery 1.9.1 on the extensions dropdown, and then toggling the "migrate 1.1.0" slider in the JS section.. [pic here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuZNl.jpg)

Even with my example working *somewhat*, AND importing the same things in my html, the HTML doesn't pick up the custom jQuery function in the external code and get:

`$(...).sparkline is not a function`

Does anyone have any experience with this library? I've followed the docs but theres **something i'm obviously missing.**

SOS : ( or maybe reccomend other sparkline packages? : (

Thank you soooo much for your time!

UPDATE:

Still fails to recognize sparkline code with the cdn instead of [downloaded files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZKRO.jpg) : (

Comment: The error occures when you don't have sparkline included in your page. Please observe the networks requests and ensure that it is loading successfully.

Comment: Are you creating the`script tag` BEFORE using it ?

Comment: Normally it happens if you load 2 versions of jQuery....

Comment: @Hearner  yes, the script to that actually calls the function is the last script tag at the page

Comment: @epascarello I only have one script tag and it looks like this:
```<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>```

Its the first script tag at the bottom of the body tag

Comment: @31piy yep.. All 200 (successfully loaded, but im going to try again with the CDN suggested below)

Answer (score 2):

Do not know why, but when I put the sparkline reference right before where I use it, the problem's gone.

It looks like:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
    $jq(document).ready(function() {
        $jq(".sparkline_bar").sparkline([5,6,7,2,0,-4,-2,4], {
            type: 'bar'});
        //Some other things.
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

I had JS code that was conflicting with the sparklines code in the  tags to initialize the lines.

Fixed by simply initializing the lines FIRST before any other JS stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is no jquery import after spakline.

This is right:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
```

This is wrong:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
...
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
```